# Decreased blood acidity

Tags: arabica, acid

How can blood acidity be prevented by eating coffee and its acidity level balanced to alkaline ?
Of course, except for drinking a lot of water.

Comment: Welcome! Please add details what you mean by “blood acidity” - preferably a source, thanks.

Comment: @Stephie hello , link for details and source , There are many examples of references to acidification of blood and its relationship to coffee. https://eatcultured.com/blogs/our-awesome-blog/acid-in-coffee

Comment: @Merlin, the only reference to blood in the post you mention is where one of the acids in coffee is being researched for its potential impact on blood pressure. Attempting to actively self-manage the pH of your blood smells a lot like pseudo-science

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our blood ph level drives our respiratory rate, if we are not breathing out enough CO2 we build up carbonic acid which in turn drives our respiratory rate higher until such time we have reduced our PH levels to a 'normal' range which is around 7.35 to 7.45 Ph.
 Simply put it's not possible to alter blood acidity or alkalinity without making yourself sick and usually ending up in an ICU.
The human body (and other species) uses a process called homeostasis which is our autopilot of systems integration to keep us alive and relatively healthy. Illness and chronic disease can impact on our bodies ability to balance itself but it will do it's best to keep its chemistry balanced.
There are a number of cases (Illness) where php drops (acidity) and the body moves other chemicals around to balance this which can have a knock on effect throwing other systems out (I.e. cardiac arrhythmias due to sodium/ potassium  / calcium imbalances etc.). There are other cases where calcium.is scavenged from our skeletal system (which can cause early onset osteoporosis, and a cohort of other nasties.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5118493/

I studied medicine and am a registered Paramedic and a massive consumer of fresh ground black coffee.
Hope this helps....